# Unable to write data to serial port in php

Tags: php, serial-port

I am creating a code in which data can pass from USB to serial port. Problem is that I am unable to write data to serial port on windows system in php. Device has been connect and opened successfully and baud rate, parity, length, stop bits, flow control are set accordingly with no error.

When I am sending data to serial port no error or output will there. Anyone can help with? I am using php serial port class to do this.

```
include 'src/PhpSerial.php';
$serial = new PhpSerial;
$serial->deviceSet('COM3');
$serial->confBaudRate(9600);
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
$serial->confFlowControl("none");
$serial->deviceOpen();
$serial->sendMessage(49); 
/* 49 is Ascii value of 1 (Light will ON on press 2 and will off on press 1) */

$serial->deviceClose();
```

I used my device with a software coolterm on which its working fine. But when I am doing this task from php code, I unable to do that.

Anyone?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the answer

```
exec("mode COM3: BAUD=9600 PARITY=n DATA=8 STOP=1 to=off dtr=off rts=off");
    $fp =fopen("COM3", "w");
    // $fp = fopen('/dev/ttyUSB0','r+'); //use this for Linux
    fwrite($fp, 2); //write string to serial
    fclose($fp);
    return;
```

Answer (score -1):

Install a virtual Machine and do it in *nix.

Trust me, I lost a lot of time.